# Expectations of functions of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

so I am a TA in an intro stats class and I stumbled upon a brain teaser question that even I am not quite sure how to solve. I thought some of you might be able to help. The question is as follows:

You have a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. The students are asked to calculate the $E[f(X)]$ for three functions (and the question specifies that for the last two, you should express the solution as the standard normal CDF, $\phi$:

a) $f(x)=e^{ax}$ where a is an element of $R$

b) $f(x)=(e^{ax}-b)^+$ where a is an element of $R$ and $b>0$$

c) $f(x)=(x-a)^+$ where a is an element of $R$

So, my approach to part (a) was calculating the same as you would for a moment generating function (i.e. just expand it to get $1 + aE(x) + a^2E(x^2)/2! + a^3E(x^3)/3!+...+$) however, I am not sure that that is the correct approach to this question. Then, for the last two questions, I am not sure how to approach them. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For a), did you try $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax}f(x)dx$?

Comment: I think you need to write $e^{ax-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}}$ and then do some algebra to close the square

Comment: ... and similarly, (b) and (c) are integrals over appropriate intervals.

Comment: to evaluate $b$ and $c$, you need use error functions, i.e. CDF of normal distribution. Note that the answer to $b$ should be in a similar form to the Black-Scholes formula in stochastic finance.

Comment: Lost1...do you have a source for this that I might be able to read on?

Comment: what source do you want? you can just write down the integral and evaluate them via change of variable using CDF of normal? when do you need it by? i would do them for you if i can be bothered, but i dont have time right now

Answer (score 3):

Let us solve (c) and see if you can adapt the ideas below to (a) and (b).

- First, to compute $E[f(X)]$ by expanding $f$ into a series is definitely not the first idea one should try. Rather, use the definition (in the density case), that is,
  $$
  E[f(X)]=\int_\mathbb Rf(x)g(x)\mathrm dx,
  $$
  where $g$ is the density of the distribution of $X$.
- Second, $X=\sigma Z+\mu$ where $Z$ is standard normal hence it suffices to solve (c) when $X$ has density $\varphi$. Thus, one looks for
  $$
  E[f(X)]=\int_a^\infty (x-a)\varphi(x)\mathrm dx.
  $$
- Third, $\varphi'(x)=-x\varphi(x)$ hence $(x-a)\varphi(x)=-\varphi'(x)-a\varphi(x)$ and
  $$
  E[f(X)]=\left.-\varphi(x)\right|_a^\infty-a\int_a^\infty\varphi(x)\mathrm dx=\varphi(a)-a+a\Phi(a).
  $$

Answer (score -2):

For (a): The MGF of the normal distribution can be found here: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lebanon/notes/mgf.pdf‎

You basically find the MGF of the standard normal distribution and use that to calculate the MGF of the normal distribution.

For (b), (c) use linearity of expectation.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the solution to part (a) would essentially be $e^{a\mu}e^{0.5\sigma^2a^2}$?

Comment: Neither of the functions in (b) and (c) is linear.

Comment: That is my problem with (b) and (c) and the reason why I am not sure how to solve them. The MGF approach would not work there.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: I thought $E[e^{ax}-b]=E[e^{ax}]-E[b]=E[e^{ax}]-b$, no?

Comment: @Kuai...because the functions are not linear implies that you can use the linearity of expectation

Comment: @Kuai $(e^{ax}-b)^+$ is not the same as $e^{ax}-b$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland What does the "+" in superscript mean?

Comment: @Kuai http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts

Comment: The + refers to the positive part of the function